# On topologically equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let the metric $d'$ be given by $d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$
>
> Show that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent.

I want to show that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent.
That means that if we have an open set $U$ with regards to $d$, $U$ is open with regards to $d'$ and vice versa.

> So let $U$ be open with regards to $d'$.

Then exists for every $u\in U$ an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon^{d'}(u)\subseteq U$.

Now I have to find for every $u\in U$ an $\delta >0$ such that $B_\delta^{d}(u)\subseteq U$.

I want to give $\delta$ such that holds $B_\delta^d(u)\subseteq B_\varepsilon^{d'}(u)$.

> How to give $\delta$?

I have to choose $\delta$ such that $d(v,u)<\delta\Rightarrow d'(v,u)<\varepsilon$.

We choose $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Let $v\in B_\delta^d(u)$. Then we have $d'(v,u)=\frac{d(v,u)}{1+d(v,u)}\stackrel{!}{\leq} d(v,u)<\delta=\varepsilon$.

So we have $v\in B_\varepsilon^{d'}(u)$ and conclude $B_\delta^d(u)\subseteq B_\varepsilon^{d'}(u)\subseteq U$ as desired.

Now:

> Let $U$ be open with regards to $d$.

Then exists for every $u\in U$ an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon^d(u)\subseteq U$.

Again I want to choose for every $u\in U$ a $\delta > 0$ such that

$B_\delta^{d'}(u)\subseteq B_\varepsilon^d(u)\subseteq U$.

So $d'(v,u)<\delta\Rightarrow d(u,v)<\varepsilon$.

> How can this be done?

I want to find a reasonable choice for $\delta$, so for a sketch we have

$d'(u,v)<\delta\Leftrightarrow \frac{d(u,v)}{1+d(u,v)}<\delta\Leftrightarrow d(u,v)=\delta+\delta d(u,v)\Leftrightarrow d(u,v)(1-\delta)<\delta$.

If $\delta\in (0,1)$ we have:

$d(u,v)<\frac{\delta}{1-\delta}$

If $\delta \geq 1$, then there is nothing to show (can we say so?), since the LHS would be negative, while the RHS is positive.

Is this thought sensible, do a calculation like above, to restrict the choice of $\delta$?

So I thought about choosing $\delta =\min\{1,\varepsilon\}$

I struggle to complete the proof.
Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second case (to show $B^{d'}_\delta(u) \subseteq B^d_\varepsilon(u)$) you can choose
$$
\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}
$$ and $\delta > 0$ because $\varepsilon > 0$.

Now you can directly check that this choice works. For if $$d'(u, v) < \delta$$

then $$\frac{d(u,v)}{1 + d(u, v)} < \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}$$

so since both denominators are positive, cross-multiplying preserves the inequality sign, and we get $$d(u,v) + \varepsilon d(u, v) < \varepsilon + \varepsilon d(u, v)$$

and finally cancelling $\varepsilon d(u, v)$ on both sides gives
$$
d(u, v) < \varepsilon
$$ as desired.

Comment: How did I miss that... Thank you.

Comment: But is my first case even correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: If by first case, you meant your work showing $B^d_\delta(u) \subseteq B^{d'}_\varepsilon(u)$, then yes it is correct.